# How can I use the 'afade' parameter in ffmpeg-python without getting an 'option not found' error?

Tags: python, ffmpeg-python

I am using the ffmpeg library with python to add subtitles and a video as an overlay to a background still image.  This code is working fine, but I want to use the `afade` parameter.  The code without the `afade` parameter works fine.  However, when I add the `afade` code in, I am getting the error.

**Error**

```
Unrecognized option 'af fade=t=out:st=10:d=2'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

**Code**

```
    try:
        subprocess.check_call([
        'ffmpeg',
        '-i', source_file,
        '-i', padding_image_file,
        '-filter_complex',
            '[0:v]scale=iw/'+ video_scale + ':ih/' + video_scale + ',setsar=1[main];'
            '[1:v]scale=720:1280[pad];'
            '[pad][main]overlay=' + video_overlay_x + ':'+ video_overlay_y + ',subtitles=' + subtitles_file + ':force_style=\'Alignment=6,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize=8,MarginL=2,MarginV=20\'',
        '-c:a', 'copy', '-af "afade=t=out:st=14.2:d=0.8"', '-crf', '20', '-preset', 'fast', '-movflags', '+faststart',
        '-y', output_file
    ])
```

I have tried multiple options and ways to using this -af in different ways but am still getting the "option not found" error.

Comment: Have you tried `'-c:a', 'copy', '-af', 'afade=t=out:st=14.2:d=0.8', '-crf', ` ?

Comment: Right.  The parameter name and its values need to be in separate strings, just like you did with the other parameters.  And you don't need the double-quotes in that case; you have already done the parsing that the shell would have done.

Comment: Thank you both.  I am still trying to get my head around the flag combinations.  In doing this, I received an error `Filtergraph 'afade=t=out:st=14.2:d=0.8' was defined for audio output stream 0:1 but codec copy was selected.
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.`. I am assuming this means that I am trying to combine the wrong outputs?